# Can One Time Passwords be used as identifiers?

Tags: encryption, obfuscation, one-time-password, data-masking

If I have bunch of [OTPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_password) mixed and if I know all of their generation seeds (the OPT URI) can I group by source URI?

I have a  use case there I need the system to be 100% blind to the data relationships that its passing around. 
For example: Users enter OTPs from their smartphones instead of their logins it should become very difficult identify entries by one user. As data is exported of the system that has OPT seeds is it possible to reestablish entry's ownership?

Answer (score 2):

That's possible, but with a big complexity. You will need to generate codes for all seeds you have and then find if there is any match.

Also, there is a chance to receive the same code for different seeds at some moment. To avoid this problem you can ask a user for several consecutive codes, this significantly decreases the possibility of codes matching just by case.